# Google Authenticator keeps crashing after OS upgrade

Tags: google-authenticator

I had no problem using Google Authenticator for the first month.  Two weeks ago, my phone's operating system upgraded and now Authenticator will not work.

I have uninstalled it, re-downloaded it, and reinstalled.  No matter what function I choose (sync time, setup) I get an error message that Authenticator has stopped working.  Also, since I need the two-factoring for our website, the codes stopped working on that.  I keep reporting the issue to Google but of course, have had no response.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Because your work is affected, until this issue is resolved you can use [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.fedorahosted.freeotp) app for two-factor authentication. I tested it now and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't access to **Google Authenticator** in any way, I suggest trying [Duo Mobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.duosecurity.duomobile) or [FreOTP Authenticator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.fedorahosted.freeotp)

I tried Duo Mobile and I personally use it for my personal Google Account. It works like a charm. Feel free to draw feedback if that resolves the question for you.